# Repetir processo ao receber entrada inválida

Tags: java

Não to conseguindo fazer com que esse programa repita depois que o usuário colocar uma resposta inválida.

Caso ele/ela digite uma resposta não valida como poderia ser feito para o programa rodar novamente para ser colocado a resposta de acordo como solicitado?

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputValidationString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
        
        
        System.out.println(" Do you like to code?:");
        String liketocode=in.nextLine();
        
        
        if (liketocode.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
            System.out.println("That's great! I do too!");
        } if (liketocode.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) { 
            System.out.println("That's ok. There are many other wonderful things in life to learn.");
        } else { System.out.println("Invalid Response! Please answer with a 'Y' or 'N'.");
        
        } while (liketocode.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")||(liketocode.equalsIgnoreCase("N")));
    
        in.close();
        
        // Author : Messias Kennedy             
    } // the end of main 
} // the end of public class
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que seu código está estruturado de forma errada. Primeiramente a condição do `while` parece invertida se sua intenção é repetir algo enquanto a entrada for inválida. Segundo, o while não faz nada, o ponto-e-vírgula ao final dele deveria ser um bloco de código para ser repetido ou então você teria ter usado um bloco `do` antes do `while` (como é feito no exemplo).

Uma possível solução seria:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String liketocode;
        boolean respostaValida;
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Do you like to code?:");
            liketocode = in.nextLine();
            
            respostaValida = respostaÉValida(liketocode);
            if (!respostaValida) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Response! Please answer with a 'Y' or 'N'.");
            }
        }
        while (!respostaValida);

        if (liketocode.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
            System.out.println("That's great! I do too!");
        else if (liketocode.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
            System.out.println("That's ok. There are many other wonderful things in life to learn.");        
    
        in.close();           
    }

    private static boolean respostaÉValida(String resposta)
    {
        return resposta.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") || resposta.equalsIgnoreCase("N");
    }
}
```

[Veja funcionando no Repl.it.](https://replit.com/@jfbueno/ptso508911)